# Why material design ui doesn't render as it should?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-material

I'm making a SPA using AngularJS, right now I'm implementing angular-material, but I don't know why my view is not rendering as it should, this is the [sample](http://codepen.io/kyleledbetter/pen/gbQOaV) I followed, but what I get isn't the same.

I don't see any problem in my code, could anyone help me figure it out?(ngRoute wont run in this snippet, I know, but I'll replace the ng-view with a structure of a view template)

```js
'use strict';
var quaestio = angular.module('Quaestio', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMdIcons', 'ngRoute', 'smart-table']);

quaestio.config(function($routeProvider, $mdThemingProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: './views/home.html',
      controller: 'main-ctrl'
    })
    .when('/about', {
      templateUrl: "./views/about-company.html",
      controller: 'main-ctrl'
    })
    .when('/contact', {
      templateUrl: "./views/contact.html",
      controller: 'main-ctrl'
    })
    .when('/faq', {
      templateUrl: "./views/faq.html",
      controller: 'table-ctrl'
    })
    .when('/edit-faq', {
      templateUrl: "./views/edit-faq.html",
      controller: 'main-ctrl'
    })
    .when('/general', {
      templateUrl: "./views/general.html",
      controller: 'main-ctrl'
    })
    .when('/personnel', {
      templateUrl: "./views/about-personnel.html",
      controller: 'main-ctrl'
    })
    .when('/settings', {
      templateUrl: "./views/settings.html",
      controller: 'main-ctrl'
    })
    .when('/terms', {
      templateUrl: "./views/terms.html",
      controller: 'main-ctrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });

  var customBlueMap = $mdThemingProvider.extendPalette('light-blue', {
    'contrastDefaultColor': 'light',
    'contrastDarkColors': ['50'],
    '50': 'ffffff'
  });
  $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('customBlue', customBlueMap);
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('customBlue', {
      'default': '500',
      'hue-1': '50'
    })
    .accentPalette('pink');
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('input', 'default')
    .primaryPalette('grey')
});

/**
 * Main Data and Functions Controller
 */
quaestio.controller('main-ctrl', function($scope, $http) {

  var refresh = function() {
    $http.get('/quaestioJS').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.resdata = data;
      $scope.limpiar();
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("Errorazo.");
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  refresh();

  $scope.agregar = function() {
    $scope.tmpdata.query = "INSERT INTO personas SET ?";
    $http.post('/quaestioJS', $scope.tmpdata).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      refresh();
      $scope.limpiar();
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("Errorazo.");
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  $scope.eliminar = function(id) {
    var query = "DELETE FROM personas WHERE ID = " + id;
    $http.delete('/quaestioJS/' + query).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      refresh();
      $scope.limpiar();
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("Errorazo.");
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  $scope.editar = function(id) {
    var query = "SELECT * FROM personas WHERE ID = " + id;
    $http.get('/quaestioJS/' + query).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.tmpdata = data[0];
      console.log();
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("Errorazo.");
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  $scope.actualizar = function() {
    $scope.tmpdata.query = "UPDATE personas SET ? WHERE ID = " + $scope.tmpdata.ID;
    $http.post('/quaestioJS', $scope.tmpdata).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      refresh();
      $scope.limpiar();
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("Errorazo.");
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  $scope.limpiar = function() {
    $scope.tmpdata = "";
  }
});

/**
 * Modern Design Controller
 */
quaestio.controller('md-ctrl', ['$scope', '$mdBottomSheet', '$mdSidenav', '$mdDialog', '$http', '$location',
  function($scope, $mdBottomSheet, $mdSidenav, $mdDialog, $http, $location) {
    $scope.colors = [{
      color: 'red'
    }, {
      color: 'blue'
    }, {
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      color: 'yellow'
    }];
    $scope.prueba = function(path) {
      $location.path(path);
    }
    $scope.menu = [

      {
        id: '/home',
        title: 'Inicio',
        icon: 'home'
      }, {
        id: '/about',
        title: 'Sobre La Empresa',
        icon: 'info'
      }, {
        id: '/personnel',
        title: 'Sobre Nosotros',
        icon: 'people'
      }, {
        id: '/terms',
        title: 'Terminos de Uso',
        icon: 'account_balance'
      }, {
        id: '/faq',
        title: 'Preguntas Frecuentes',
        icon: 'question_answer'
      }, {
        id: '/contact',
        title: 'Contactanos',
        icon: 'quick_contacts_mail'
      }, {
        id: '/communities',
        title: 'Comunidades',
        icon: 'extension'
      }, {
        id: '/general',
        title: 'Generalidades',
        icon: 'dashboard'
      }
    ];
    $scope.admin = [{
      link: '',
      title: 'Salir de sesion',
      icon: 'exit_to_app'
    }, {
      link: 'showListBottomSheet($event)',
      title: 'Configuracion',
      icon: 'settings'
    }];

    $scope.dynamicelements = {

      tabTitle: '',
      page: '',
      username: '',
      email: ''

    };

    $scope.alert = '';

    $scope.toggleSidenav = function(menuId) {
      $mdSidenav(menuId).toggle();
    };

    $scope.showListBottomSheet = function($event) {
      $scope.alert = '';
      $mdBottomSheet.show({
        templateUrl: 'views/settings.html',
        controller: 'ListBottomSheetCtrl',
        targetEvent: $event
      }).then(function(clickedItem) {
        $scope.alert = clickedItem.name + ' Clickeado!';
      });
    };

    $scope.showAdd = function(ev) {
      $mdDialog.show({
          controller: funcDialogController,
          template: '',
          targetEvent: ev
        })
        .then(function(answer) {
          $scope.alert = 'Dijiste que tu informacion era "' + answer + '".';
        }, function() {
          $scope.alert = 'Cancelaste la operacion.';
        });
    };
    $scope.funcChangePage = function(id) {
      $scope.dynamicelements.page = id;
      console.log(id);
    }
  }
]);

/**
 * Option Menu Controller
 */
quaestio.controller('options-ctrl', function($scope, $mdBottomSheet) {
  $scope.items = [{
    name: 'Subir',
    icon: 'upload'
  }, {
    name: 'Copiar',
    icon: 'copy'
  }, {
    name: 'Imprimir esta pagina',
    icon: 'print'
  }];

  $scope.listItemClick = function($index) {
    var clickedItem = $scope.items[$index];
    $mdBottomSheet.hide(clickedItem);
  };
});

/**
 * Data Table Controller
 */
quaestio.controller('table-ctrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.tabledata = [{
      date: new Date('1987-05-21'),
      question: 'Como se llama la compania?',
      answer: 'Quaestio'
    }, {
      date: new Date('1987-05-21'),
      question: 'Quienes lo empezaron?',
      answer: 'Carlos Cornejo y Jonathan Solorzano'
    }, {
      date: new Date('1987-05-21'),
      question: 'Como surgio?',
      answer: 'Como una start up.'
    }];


  }
]);

function funcDialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
  $scope.hide = function() {
    $mdDialog.hide();
  };
  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $mdDialog.cancel();
  };
  $scope.answer = function(answer) {
    $mdDialog.hide(answer);
  };
};

quaestio.directive('userAvatar', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: './views/avatar.html'
  };
});

quaestio.directive('mdTable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      headers: '=',
      content: '=',
      sortable: '=',
      filters: '=',
      customClass: '=customClass',
      thumbs: '=',
      count: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope, $filter, $window) {
      var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');
      $scope.tablePage = 0;
      $scope.nbOfPages = function() {
          return Math.ceil($scope.content.length / $scope.count);
        },
        $scope.handleSort = function(field) {
          if ($scope.sortable.indexOf(field) > -1) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        };
      $scope.order = function(predicate, reverse) {
        $scope.content = orderBy($scope.content, predicate, reverse);
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
      };
      $scope.order($scope.sortable[0], false);
      $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
        return new Array(num);
      };
      $scope.goToPage = function(page) {
        $scope.tablePage = page;
      };
    },
    template: angular.element(document.querySelector('#md-table-template')).html()
  }
});
```

```css
md-content.md-default-theme {
  background-color: #eee;
}
md-card {
  background-color: #fff;
}
md-card h2:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}
md-toolbar .md-button.md-default-theme {
  border-radius: 99%;
}
h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.md-toolbar-tools-bottom {
  font-size: small;
}
.md-toolbar-tools-bottom:last-child {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
md-toolbar:not(.md-hue-1),
.md-fab {
  fill: #fff;
}
md-sidenav {
  fill: #737373;
}
md-sidenav ng-md-icon {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}
.user-avatar {
  border-radius: 99%;
}
.sites-list .md-button {
  color: inherit;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Quaestio">

<head lang="es">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Quaestio - Administration</title>

  <!--Stylesheets ================================================================== -->
  <!-- Angular Material CSS now available via Google CDN; version 0.8 used here -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.3/angular-material.min.css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body layout="row" ng-controller="md-ctrl">

  <!-- Barra lateral izquierda ================================================================== -->
  <md-sidenav layout="column" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')">

    <md-toolbar class="md-tall md-hue-2">
      <!-- Inicio del toolbar donde se mostrara la informacion del usuario -->
      <span flex></span>
      <div layout="column" class="md-toolbar-tools-bottom inset">
        <user-avatar></user-avatar>
        <span></span>
        <div>{{dynamicelements.username}}</div>
        <div>{{dynamicelements.email}}</div>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <!-- /Fin de toolbar -->

    <md-list class="sites-list">
      <!-- Inicio de la lista de los sitios editables y opciones de sesion-->

      <md-item ng-repeat="item in menu">
        <!-- Inicio de la lista de los sitios  -->
        <md-item-content layout="row" layout-align="start center">
          <md-button md-ripple-size="full" ng-click="prueba(item.id)">
            <ng-md-icon icon="{{item.icon}}"></ng-md-icon>{{item.title}}
          </md-button>
        </md-item-content>
      </md-item>
      <!-- /Fin de lista de sitios -->

      <md-divider></md-divider>

      <md-subheader>Sesion</md-subheader>
      <md-item ng-repeat="item in admin">
        <!-- Inicio de la lista de opciones de sesion -->
        <md-item-content layout="row" layout-align="start center">
          <md-button md-ripple-size="full" ng-click="prueba(item.id)">
            <ng-md-icon icon="{{item.icon}}"></ng-md-icon>
            {{item.title}}
          </md-button>
        </md-item-content>
      </md-item>
      <!-- /Fin de opciones de sesion -->

    </md-list>
    <!-- /Fin de listado -->

  </md-sidenav>

  <!-- Body of App ================================================================================= -->
  <div layout="column" class="relative" layout-fill role="main">

    <md-button class="md-fab md-fab-bottom-right" aria-label="Add" ng-click="showAdd($event)">
      <!-- Boton agregar presente solo en el panel de usuarios -->
      <ng-md-icon icon="add"></ng-md-icon>
    </md-button>
    <!-- /Fin de boton -->

    <md-toolbar ng-show="!showSearch">
      <!--Inicio del toolbar de navegacion-->

      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <!--Inicio del panel de opciones-->
        <md-button ng-click="toggleSidenav('left')" hide-gt-md aria-label="Menu">
          <ng-md-icon icon="menu"></ng-md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <h3>
                    Administracion - Quaestio
                </h3>
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button aria-label="Search" ng-click="showSearch = !showSearch">
          <ng-md-icon icon="search"></ng-md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <md-button aria-label="Open Settings" ng-click="showListBottomSheet($event)">
          <ng-md-icon icon="more_vert"></ng-md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </div>
      <!--/Fin de panel de navegacion-->

      <md-tabs md-stretch-tabs class="md-primary" md-selected="">
        <!--Inicio de tabs de toolbar-->
        <md-tab id="tab1" aria-controls="tab1-content">
          {{dynamicelements.tabTitle}}
        </md-tab>
      </md-tabs>
      <!--/Fin de tabs-->

    </md-toolbar>
    <!--/Fin de toolbar-->

    <md-toolbar class="md-hue-1" ng-show="showSearch">
      <!--Inicio de toolbar de opciones para buscar-->
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <md-button ng-click="showSearch = !showSearch" aria-label="Back">
          <ng-md-icon icon="arrow_back"></ng-md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <h3 flex="10">
                    Atras
                </h3>
        <md-input-container md-theme="input" flex>
          <label>&nbsp;</label>
          <input ng-model="search.who" placeholder="Buscar">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-button aria-label="Search" ng-click="showSearch = !showSearch">
          <ng-md-icon icon="search"></ng-md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <md-button aria-label="Open Settings" ng-click="showListBottomSheet($event)">
          <ng-md-icon icon="more_vert"></ng-md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <!--/Fin de toolbar -->

    <md-content flex md-scroll>
      <!--Inicio del contenido de sitios-->
      <ui-view layout="column" layout-fill layout-padding>
        <div class="inset"></div>
        <md-card flex-gt-sm="90" flex-gt-md="80" flex-gt-lg="85">
          <md-card-content>
            <div layout="column" layout-sm="column" layout-padding style="padding: 24px;">
              <div class="row text-center">
                <h2>Informacion de Contacto</h2>
              </div>
              <md-divider md-inset></md-divider>
              <br />
              <br />
              <div class="row">
                <md-input-container class="md-icon-float">
                  <label>Correo</label>
                  <md-icon src="./files/img/correo.png"></md-icon>
                  <input />
                </md-input-container>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <md-input-container class="md-icon-float">
                  <label>Direccion</label>
                  <md-icon src="./files/img/direccion.png"></md-icon>
                  <input />
                </md-input-container>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <md-input-container class="md-icon-float">
                  <label>Telefono</label>
                  <md-icon src="./files/img/telefono.png"></md-icon>
                  <input />
                </md-input-container>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <md-input-container class="md-icon-float">
                  <label>Nombre de Compania</label>
                  <md-icon src="./files/img/compania.png"></md-icon>
                  <input />
                </md-input-container>
              </div>
            </div>

          </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
      </ui-view>
    </md-content>
    <!--/Fin de contenido de sitios-->

  </div>


  <!-- Dependecies ================================================================== -->
  <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>


  <!-- Angular Material Javascript now available via Google CDN; version 0.8 used here -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.3/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.0/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular-material-icons/0.4.0/angular-material-icons.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-smart-table/2.0.3/smart-table.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see in the snippet, the input labels are not in the correct position, the animations are a bit slow, the animation when positioning the mouse on the search button are not like in the sample.

Answer (score 0):

The problems you're facing is because of the conflicts between bootstrap and angular material. They don't go together very well. The sample you're following does not include bootstrap. You can see better alignment in the below snippet without bootstrap:

```js
'use strict';
var quaestio = angular.module('Quaestio', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMdIcons', 'ngRoute', 'smart-table']);

quaestio.config(function($routeProvider, $mdThemingProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: './views/home.html',
      controller: 'main-ctrl'
    })
    .when('/about', {
      templateUrl: "./views/about-company.html",
      controller: 'main-ctrl'
    })
    .when('/contact', {
      templateUrl: "./views/contact.html",
      controller: 'main-ctrl'
    })
    .when('/faq', {
      templateUrl: "./views/faq.html",
      controller: 'table-ctrl'
    })
    .when('/edit-faq', {
      templateUrl: "./views/edit-faq.html",
      controller: 'main-ctrl'
    })
    .when('/general', {
      templateUrl: "./views/general.html",
      controller: 'main-ctrl'
    })
    .when('/personnel', {
      templateUrl: "./views/about-personnel.html",
      controller: 'main-ctrl'
    })
    .when('/settings', {
      templateUrl: "./views/settings.html",
      controller: 'main-ctrl'
    })
    .when('/terms', {
      templateUrl: "./views/terms.html",
      controller: 'main-ctrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });

  var customBlueMap = $mdThemingProvider.extendPalette('light-blue', {
    'contrastDefaultColor': 'light',
    'contrastDarkColors': ['50'],
    '50': 'ffffff'
  });
  $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('customBlue', customBlueMap);
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('customBlue', {
      'default': '500',
      'hue-1': '50'
    })
    .accentPalette('pink');
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('input', 'default')
    .primaryPalette('grey')
});

/**
 * Main Data and Functions Controller
 */
quaestio.controller('main-ctrl', function($scope, $http) {

  var refresh = function() {
    $http.get('/quaestioJS').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.resdata = data;
      $scope.limpiar();
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("Errorazo.");
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  refresh();

  $scope.agregar = function() {
    $scope.tmpdata.query = "INSERT INTO personas SET ?";
    $http.post('/quaestioJS', $scope.tmpdata).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      refresh();
      $scope.limpiar();
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("Errorazo.");
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  $scope.eliminar = function(id) {
    var query = "DELETE FROM personas WHERE ID = " + id;
    $http.delete('/quaestioJS/' + query).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      refresh();
      $scope.limpiar();
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("Errorazo.");
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  $scope.editar = function(id) {
    var query = "SELECT * FROM personas WHERE ID = " + id;
    $http.get('/quaestioJS/' + query).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.tmpdata = data[0];
      console.log();
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("Errorazo.");
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  $scope.actualizar = function() {
    $scope.tmpdata.query = "UPDATE personas SET ? WHERE ID = " + $scope.tmpdata.ID;
    $http.post('/quaestioJS', $scope.tmpdata).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      refresh();
      $scope.limpiar();
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("Errorazo.");
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  $scope.limpiar = function() {
    $scope.tmpdata = "";
  }
});

/**
 * Modern Design Controller
 */
quaestio.controller('md-ctrl', ['$scope', '$mdBottomSheet', '$mdSidenav', '$mdDialog', '$http', '$location',
  function($scope, $mdBottomSheet, $mdSidenav, $mdDialog, $http, $location) {
    $scope.colors = [{
      color: 'red'
    }, {
      color: 'blue'
    }, {
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      color: 'yellow'
    }];
    $scope.prueba = function(path) {
      $location.path(path);
    }
    $scope.menu = [

      {
        id: '/home',
        title: 'Inicio',
        icon: 'home'
      }, {
        id: '/about',
        title: 'Sobre La Empresa',
        icon: 'info'
      }, {
        id: '/personnel',
        title: 'Sobre Nosotros',
        icon: 'people'
      }, {
        id: '/terms',
        title: 'Terminos de Uso',
        icon: 'account_balance'
      }, {
        id: '/faq',
        title: 'Preguntas Frecuentes',
        icon: 'question_answer'
      }, {
        id: '/contact',
        title: 'Contactanos',
        icon: 'quick_contacts_mail'
      }, {
        id: '/communities',
        title: 'Comunidades',
        icon: 'extension'
      }, {
        id: '/general',
        title: 'Generalidades',
        icon: 'dashboard'
      }
    ];
    $scope.admin = [{
      link: '',
      title: 'Salir de sesion',
      icon: 'exit_to_app'
    }, {
      link: 'showListBottomSheet($event)',
      title: 'Configuracion',
      icon: 'settings'
    }];

    $scope.dynamicelements = {

      tabTitle: '',
      page: '',
      username: '',
      email: ''

    };

    $scope.alert = '';

    $scope.toggleSidenav = function(menuId) {
      $mdSidenav(menuId).toggle();
    };

    $scope.showListBottomSheet = function($event) {
      $scope.alert = '';
      $mdBottomSheet.show({
        templateUrl: 'views/settings.html',
        controller: 'ListBottomSheetCtrl',
        targetEvent: $event
      }).then(function(clickedItem) {
        $scope.alert = clickedItem.name + ' Clickeado!';
      });
    };

    $scope.showAdd = function(ev) {
      $mdDialog.show({
          controller: funcDialogController,
          template: '',
          targetEvent: ev
        })
        .then(function(answer) {
          $scope.alert = 'Dijiste que tu informacion era "' + answer + '".';
        }, function() {
          $scope.alert = 'Cancelaste la operacion.';
        });
    };
    $scope.funcChangePage = function(id) {
      $scope.dynamicelements.page = id;
      console.log(id);
    }
  }
]);

/**
 * Option Menu Controller
 */
quaestio.controller('options-ctrl', function($scope, $mdBottomSheet) {
  $scope.items = [{
    name: 'Subir',
    icon: 'upload'
  }, {
    name: 'Copiar',
    icon: 'copy'
  }, {
    name: 'Imprimir esta pagina',
    icon: 'print'
  }];

  $scope.listItemClick = function($index) {
    var clickedItem = $scope.items[$index];
    $mdBottomSheet.hide(clickedItem);
  };
});

/**
 * Data Table Controller
 */
quaestio.controller('table-ctrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.tabledata = [{
      date: new Date('1987-05-21'),
      question: 'Como se llama la compania?',
      answer: 'Quaestio'
    }, {
      date: new Date('1987-05-21'),
      question: 'Quienes lo empezaron?',
      answer: 'Carlos Cornejo y Jonathan Solorzano'
    }, {
      date: new Date('1987-05-21'),
      question: 'Como surgio?',
      answer: 'Como una start up.'
    }];


  }
]);

function funcDialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
  $scope.hide = function() {
    $mdDialog.hide();
  };
  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $mdDialog.cancel();
  };
  $scope.answer = function(answer) {
    $mdDialog.hide(answer);
  };
};

quaestio.directive('userAvatar', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: './views/avatar.html'
  };
});

quaestio.directive('mdTable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      headers: '=',
      content: '=',
      sortable: '=',
      filters: '=',
      customClass: '=customClass',
      thumbs: '=',
      count: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope, $filter, $window) {
      var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');
      $scope.tablePage = 0;
      $scope.nbOfPages = function() {
          return Math.ceil($scope.content.length / $scope.count);
        },
        $scope.handleSort = function(field) {
          if ($scope.sortable.indexOf(field) > -1) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        };
      $scope.order = function(predicate, reverse) {
        $scope.content = orderBy($scope.content, predicate, reverse);
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
      };
      $scope.order($scope.sortable[0], false);
      $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
        return new Array(num);
      };
      $scope.goToPage = function(page) {
        $scope.tablePage = page;
      };
    },
    template: angular.element(document.querySelector('#md-table-template')).html()
  }
});
```

```css
md-content.md-default-theme {
  background-color: #eee;
}
md-card {
  background-color: #fff;
}
md-card h2:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}
md-toolbar .md-button.md-default-theme {
  border-radius: 99%;
}
h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.md-toolbar-tools-bottom {
  font-size: small;
}
.md-toolbar-tools-bottom:last-child {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
md-toolbar:not(.md-hue-1),
.md-fab {
  fill: #fff;
}
md-sidenav {
  fill: #737373;
}
md-sidenav ng-md-icon {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}
.user-avatar {
  border-radius: 99%;
}
.sites-list .md-button {
  color: inherit;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Quaestio">

<head lang="es">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Quaestio - Administration</title>

  <!--Stylesheets ================================================================== -->
  <!-- Angular Material CSS now available via Google CDN; version 0.8 used here -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.3/angular-material.min.css">

</head>

<body layout="row" ng-controller="md-ctrl">

  <!-- Barra lateral izquierda ================================================================== -->
  <md-sidenav layout="column" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')">

    <md-toolbar class="md-tall md-hue-2">
      <!-- Inicio del toolbar donde se mostrara la informacion del usuario -->
      <span flex></span>
      <div layout="column" class="md-toolbar-tools-bottom inset">
        <user-avatar></user-avatar>
        <span></span>
        <div>{{dynamicelements.username}}</div>
        <div>{{dynamicelements.email}}</div>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <!-- /Fin de toolbar -->

    <md-list class="sites-list">
      <!-- Inicio de la lista de los sitios editables y opciones de sesion-->

      <md-item ng-repeat="item in menu">
        <!-- Inicio de la lista de los sitios  -->
        <md-item-content layout="row" layout-align="start center">
          <md-button md-ripple-size="full" ng-click="prueba(item.id)">
            <ng-md-icon icon="{{item.icon}}"></ng-md-icon>{{item.title}}
          </md-button>
        </md-item-content>
      </md-item>
      <!-- /Fin de lista de sitios -->

      <md-divider></md-divider>

      <md-subheader>Sesion</md-subheader>
      <md-item ng-repeat="item in admin">
        <!-- Inicio de la lista de opciones de sesion -->
        <md-item-content layout="row" layout-align="start center">
          <md-button md-ripple-size="full" ng-click="prueba(item.id)">
            <ng-md-icon icon="{{item.icon}}"></ng-md-icon>
            {{item.title}}
          </md-button>
        </md-item-content>
      </md-item>
      <!-- /Fin de opciones de sesion -->

    </md-list>
    <!-- /Fin de listado -->

  </md-sidenav>

  <!-- Body of App ================================================================================= -->
  <div layout="column" class="relative" layout-fill role="main">

    <md-button class="md-fab md-fab-bottom-right" aria-label="Add" ng-click="showAdd($event)">
      <!-- Boton agregar presente solo en el panel de usuarios -->
      <ng-md-icon icon="add"></ng-md-icon>
    </md-button>
    <!-- /Fin de boton -->

    <md-toolbar ng-show="!showSearch">
      <!--Inicio del toolbar de navegacion-->

      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <!--Inicio del panel de opciones-->
        <md-button ng-click="toggleSidenav('left')" hide-gt-md aria-label="Menu">
          <ng-md-icon icon="menu"></ng-md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <h3>
                    Administracion - Quaestio
                </h3>
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button aria-label="Search" ng-click="showSearch = !showSearch">
          <ng-md-icon icon="search"></ng-md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <md-button aria-label="Open Settings" ng-click="showListBottomSheet($event)">
          <ng-md-icon icon="more_vert"></ng-md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </div>
      <!--/Fin de panel de navegacion-->

      <md-tabs md-stretch-tabs class="md-primary" md-selected="">
        <!--Inicio de tabs de toolbar-->
        <md-tab id="tab1" aria-controls="tab1-content">
          {{dynamicelements.tabTitle}}
        </md-tab>
      </md-tabs>
      <!--/Fin de tabs-->

    </md-toolbar>
    <!--/Fin de toolbar-->

    <md-toolbar class="md-hue-1" ng-show="showSearch">
      <!--Inicio de toolbar de opciones para buscar-->
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <md-button ng-click="showSearch = !showSearch" aria-label="Back">
          <ng-md-icon icon="arrow_back"></ng-md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <h3 flex="10">
                    Atras
                </h3>
        <md-input-container md-theme="input" flex>
          <label>&nbsp;</label>
          <input ng-model="search.who" placeholder="Buscar">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-button aria-label="Search" ng-click="showSearch = !showSearch">
          <ng-md-icon icon="search"></ng-md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <md-button aria-label="Open Settings" ng-click="showListBottomSheet($event)">
          <ng-md-icon icon="more_vert"></ng-md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <!--/Fin de toolbar -->

    <md-content flex md-scroll>
      <!--Inicio del contenido de sitios-->
      <ui-view layout="column" layout-fill layout-padding>
        <div class="inset"></div>
        <md-card flex-gt-sm="90" flex-gt-md="80" flex-gt-lg="85">
          <md-card-content>
            <div layout="column" layout-sm="column" layout-padding style="padding: 24px;">
              <div class="row text-center">
                <h2>Informacion de Contacto</h2>
              </div>
              <md-divider md-inset></md-divider>
              <br />
              <br />
              <div class="row">
                <md-input-container class="md-icon-float">
                  <label>Correo</label>
                  <md-icon src="./files/img/correo.png"></md-icon>
                  <input />
                </md-input-container>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <md-input-container class="md-icon-float">
                  <label>Direccion</label>
                  <md-icon src="./files/img/direccion.png"></md-icon>
                  <input />
                </md-input-container>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <md-input-container class="md-icon-float">
                  <label>Telefono</label>
                  <md-icon src="./files/img/telefono.png"></md-icon>
                  <input />
                </md-input-container>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <md-input-container class="md-icon-float">
                  <label>Nombre de Compania</label>
                  <md-icon src="./files/img/compania.png"></md-icon>
                  <input />
                </md-input-container>
              </div>
            </div>

          </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
      </ui-view>
    </md-content>
    <!--/Fin de contenido de sitios-->

  </div>


  <!-- Dependecies ================================================================== -->
  <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>


  <!-- Angular Material Javascript now available via Google CDN; version 0.8 used here -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.3/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.0/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular-material-icons/0.4.0/angular-material-icons.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-smart-table/2.0.3/smart-table.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Either use angular material alone or if you must use bootstrap with AngularJS, take a look at http://tilwinjoy.github.io/angular-bootstrap-material/ that I wrote.